# Deadlock even with LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

When I trigger 10 requests in 1 second, `org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException`
occurs.

Even though I marked my main method (calling repository methods inside) with `@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)` and my findBy method in repository has `@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)` annotation.

On one environment everything works fine, but on the other environment error occurs. Any ideas why error occurs? Code is the same on both environments.

Stacktrace 1:

> {"timestamp":"2017-08-21T12:18:16.16+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException","message":
>   "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction; nested exception is 
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting 
>   transaction","path":"/cars/toyota"}

Stacktrace 2:

> {"timestamp":"2017-08-21T12:11:57.57+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException","message":"could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; 
>   nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement","path":"/cars/toyota"}

Comment: database that you use?

Comment: MySQL database. I forgot to mention, sorry.

Comment: you also have some stacktrace beyond that... might want to include that also

Comment: I've just pasted two stacktraces, both occurs for the same reason. One is caught by jdbc handler,  and the other is caught by hibernate handler and thrown by Spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is thrown when you try to lock a row but the row is already locked by another transaction. So the timeout happens.

Adding the `@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)` makes it even worse because serializable level means one transaction locks entire table (modern oracle could somehow control this but for MySQl it's in fact a queue of transactions waiting to lock the same table). So 10th transaction waits for all previous 9 transactions and fails.

Actually I don't see why you need locks on `findBy` method. Logically the method should not modify the table so no need to lock at all.

I would suggest to change the logic to make one single call faster or even introduce optimistic locks (versions based) if you have concurrent modifications. Hibernate allows this by adding `@Version`.

Comment: Big logic block require that row to be locked until transaction is done. Even to prevent reading from that row. I just wonder how to prevent that deadlock? @Transactional does not lock entire table because transaction on other rows are working properly. Just transactions on same row are making troubles.